# How can I improve my JSON schema?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I have this JSON here:

```
  [{
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ -2.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 1.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ -5.449212707644754, 2.3458776596, -1.452433 ]
  }]
```

which represents a list of points in a graph. In this case we have three points for a given timestamp so this JSON describes three plots (three channels).

This holds for normal channel (i.e. a list of simple float values).
So far so good.

Unfortunately, in some cases we have the so called "minmax" channels in which each point is represented as a pair of float!

Let's take the last example and replace the middle channel (the second one) as a "minmax" channel. The problem here is that I don't know how to JSON-ize the pair of float for that "minmax" channel without ambiguity.

```
  [{
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ -2.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 1.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ 0.449212707644754, ???, 1.452433 ]
  },
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ -5.449212707644754, ???, -1.452433 ]
  }]
```

What's the best way to do it? Can I have unnamed arrays inside other arrays?
And what about deserializing such JSON in a Javascript object?

Comment: _I don't know how to JSON-ize the pair of float for that "minmax" channel without ambiguity_ Why not to use nested array?

Comment: can you show me an example? A proper SO answer will be very appreciated.

Comment: Indeed you can have array inside other arrays. That should be no problem. I don't know how the deserialization in javascript objects works. Try to insert the float-array and update the result please :)

Comment: @hindmost JSON format declares an array as a value so I need a name for that inner array. Am I right?

Comment: _I need a name for that inner array?_ Most likely you confuse arrays with objects. Objects should have named properties. Arrays should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest an array in this part, like so:

Without minimax:

```
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ [0.449212707644754], [1.11111], [1.452433] ]
  },
```

With minimax:

```
  {
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [ [0.449212707644754], [1.11111, 1.63245345], [1.452433] ]
  },
```

Then on parsing, you would only have to check how many array elements the second channel has, that way you can determine if its minimax or not. Of course it works exactly the same with channel one and three.

> When typed, an array is represented as open and closed brackets:
>   []which may contain a comma-separated list of values[ "a", "b", "c" ].
>   These values can be any JSON data type: string, number,boolean,
>   object, array, null.
>   Source: https://www.json.com/json-array

Comment: Brilliant! But from what I can see from the JSON spec http://json.org/ an array should have always a name (I mean, it should be encoded as a name,value pair), I'm missing something probably. I tell you because the JSON string is actually generated by a C# serializer so I need to find a way to define an object class which ends up serialized as your JSON.

Comment: It has a name of course, `ChannelsValues` is now of type "array of arrays". Have a look here: Array types can be of type `array`: https://www.json.com/json-array . On the C# part I cant help you, sorry

Comment: Ok, so if I serialize a "C# array of arrays of floats" I'll end up with this kind of JSON?

Comment: I would guess so, but I cannot definitivly answer that question. But it should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

If channels have some meaning, you could also consider following schema with `first`, `second` and `third` names replaced to better describe the channel.

```
{
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "Channels": {
        "first": {
            "value": -5.449212707644754
        },
        "second": {
            "min": 0.312,
            "max": 1.2312321
        },
        "third": {
            "value": -1.452433
        }
    }
}
```

Adventage of that solution is better readability. It's obvious what mean `min` and `max`. If you use nested arrays, no one will know that it's a "minmax" channel

Comment: Nice solution. Problem is I want to make the JSON stuff as lean as possible. We are going to transfer thousands of points so I was looking to something with less possilble parameter names ("first", "second", "min", "max" etc..).

Comment: If you need small file maybe you should consider other format than json? Maybe binary? Either small size or readability - you need to choose :)

Comment: @damgad: If its a minimax channel, there will be two values, if not, there will be one in the array. its very less programlogic needed to determine if minimax or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make your channel values an array of objects. This way you can name the properties of those objects rather than rely on their position to indicate their meaning. e.g.

```
{
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [
        { 
            value: -2.449212707644754
        },
        { 
            min: -2.449212707644754,
            max: 4.678432425151,
        },
        { 
            value: 1.452433
        }
    ]
}
```

Regarding JSON data size, most web servers will allow you to enable compression of HTTP responses and browsers will decompress automatically. This is super easy to enable on the server side. Compressed JSON is just as small as a binary protocol such as Google Protocol Buffers. In this case there will be lots of redundancy in the JSON so it should zip up extremely well. You could also make the property names single characters as well. e.g. v for value, n for min and x for max.

```
{
    "HistoryId": "bf39d7cfca8536b3e00e5355dff25a97715bc439a5c73d41d10a9eb0c45f2e68",
    "DateTime": "2014-05-13T09:24:49",
    "ChannelsValues": [
        { 
            v: -2.449212707644754
        },
        { 
            n: -2.449212707644754,
            x: 4.678432425151,
        },
        { 
            v: 1.452433
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Problem is I want to make the JSON stuff as lean as possible. We are going to transfer thousands of points so I was looking to something with less possilble parameter names ("value", "min", "max" etc..).

Comment: @G_G Most web servers will all you to enable compression of HTTP responses and browsers will decompress automatically. This is super easy to enable on the server side. Compressed JSON is just as small as a binary protocol such as Google Protocol Buffers. In this case there will be lots of redundancy in the JSON so it should zip up extremely well.

Comment: you could also make the property names single characters as well. e.g. v for value, n for min and x for max.